# div relations when scrolling 1 div should be stay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script>
   $().ready(function() {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv1");

        $(window).scroll(function(){            
            $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "fast" );          
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
   $().ready(function() {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv2");

        $(window).scroll(function(){            
            $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "fast" );          
        });
    });
</script>
```

//////

```
    <div id="scrollingDiv1" style="display:inline-block;float:left;">
    </div>
    <div id="scrollingDiv2" style="display:inline-block;float:right;">
    </div>
    <div id="foodInfo" style="display:absolute;float:center;">
    </div>
```

Hi, `scrollingDiv1`, `scrollingDiv2` moving (Keep element in view while scrolling) but  when we scroll `foodInfo` move too. actually `foodInfo` under these `scrollingDiv1`, `scrollingDiv2`div when these move `foodInfo` goes with other. We set `display:absolute;` but still move how we can do this. If this explanation still not enough i can share link. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your question means, but i think removing your JS code and using the CSS `position: fixed;` property should get you somewhere close.

Comment: check here i got 2 ads left and right http://sevgilezzeti.com/tarif-590 when ads move page info moves too

Comment: There is no (float:center) css property--- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp   --

Comment: display:absolute and float:center are invalid

Comment: Yes right, i deleted float center but still got problem

Comment: remove display:absolute and replace with position:absolute

Comment: changed still got same problem http://sevgilezzeti.com/tarif-590

Answer (score -1):

you can try below code:

Use position:fixed for that.

```
#foodInfo{position:fixed;}
```

Comment: `$scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "fast" );  
                $("#topBar").css("position", "fixed");
        });`
Added but not working you can check http://sevgilezzeti.com/tarif-590

Comment: display:absolute and float:center are invalid

Comment: changed both of them but still got problem

Answer (score -1):

Food info div can be positioned as fixed.

position: fixed;

If this is done then that DIV stays in a fixed position and other DIVS scroll beneath it. This is a commonly used technique in fixed header menus